# Display Name Data annotation for foreign key field

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, data-annotations

I am having a problem getting a proper display name for my foreign key field in entity framework database first. I am having the same problem as indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21868360/how-do-i-set-the-displayname-data-annotation-on-dropdownlists-from-the.)

My class:

```
public class CampaignMeta
{

    public long CampaignID;

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Campaign Name")]
    public string CampaignName;

    [Display(Name = "Campaign date created")]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateCreated;

    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateEnded;

    [Display(Name = "Campaign Type")]
    public Nullable<long> CampaignTypeID;

    public virtual CampaignType CampaignType {get;set;}
}
```

Some of my view (problem area):

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Campaign</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CampaignName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CampaignName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CampaignName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateCreated, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateCreated, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control datepicker col-md-2", placeholder = "Enter Drop-off date here..." } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateCreated, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateEnded, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateEnded, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateEnded, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CampaignTypeID, "CampaignTypeID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("CampaignTypeID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CampaignTypeID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

My foreign key is CampaignTypeID and is displaying CampaignTypeID  instead of "Campaign Type". What am i misunderstanding in a scenario like this?

Comment: There shouldn't be an issue. However, that depends largely on *how you're rendering the label for the property in your view*, which you've neglected to post. Assuming you're using something like `LabelFor`, then the display name should apply.

Comment: Hi @ChrisPratt , i do have LabelFor but it still wont budge.. i have had this issue before.please see original post for mark up of the view..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try with below code snippet.

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.CampaignTypeID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
```

OR

```
 @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CampaignTypeID, "Campaign Type", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
```

Comment: @JJDev, Jayesh's point here is that you're passing the label text, via the `"CampaignTypeID"` parameter. Either omit this parameter or actually pass what you want to appear.

Comment: This worked.Thanks guys. The explicit value defined was causing the annotation not to function properly.